# New data is not being 'added' in Highcharts in Delphi UniGUI Enviroment

Tags: javascript, delphi, highcharts, delphi-xe2

I am having an issue in Highcharts with this scenario:

- there is a bar chart created with some existing data
- if i insert a new data which the name is already existing, there is no issue (Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data shows all the correct data and values)
- if i insert a new data that is not yet existing, this is where the issue is: initially, the chart is redrawn or reloaded to show all data including the newly added one, but when i run Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data, the new data is non existent (ie. there were 2, after inserting a new one, there is still 2, should be 3)
- so now, when trying to update the data again (there are 3 in the display but 2 when calling Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data in the console), there is an error where the data is non existent (Ajax error cannot read property 'data' of undefined. Which refers to the newly added data

Does anyone have any idea on how to manipulate data in a chart (highcharts) without the need to completely refresh the browser?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you considered using the `series.update` feature to achieve that? API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, we tried it but still not working as needed.

Comment: Could you reproduce your attempt with the sample data on some online editor that I could work on?

Comment: Hi, we got it working now, needed to clear the whole data and user setdata which should include the whole array options and values.